# Pandas: how to create a new column with entries programmatically set based on another column's entries?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like the following:

```
    box boxCode  count
0  x305      K8      3
1  x305      Z8      4
2  x307      Z8      1
3  x403      Z8      6
4  x405      Z8      1
5  x510      Z8      2
```

how can I generate a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
    box boxCode  count   boxVariant
0  x305      K8      3    x305-1
1  x305      Z8      4    x305-2
2  x307      Z8      1    x307-1
3  x403      Z8      6    x403-1
4  x405      Z8      1    x405-1
5  x510      Z8      2    x510-1
```

where the boxVariant column above has entries that are basically the same as those found in the box column, except they are now numbered?

Comment: From an R angle it would be something like: library(dplyr), dataframe <- dataframe %>% group_by(box) %>% mutate(rows = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>% unite(boxVariant, box, rows, sep = "-", remove = FALSE). Just migrate that code to Python and all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby` on `box` followed by a `cumcount` operation. Concatenate the result with the original `box` column.

```
In [6]: df.box +'-' + (df.groupby('box').cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
Out[6]:
0    x305-1
1    x305-2
2    x307-1
3    x403-1
4    x405-1
5    x510-1
dtype: object
```

Comment: The most straightforward and efficient one for this problem, imo.